# DNS over VPN subdomain exception

Tags: internal-dns

I’m hosting a Munki repository on our local server for software deployment. It is reachable on a subdomain internally. Since everyone is working from home now, I’d like to mirror the repo to a webserver (for faster connection) and have the subdomain resolved by public DNS. At the same time, I’d like keep the DNS via VPN for other internal services. What is best practice to accomplish this? Thanks!

Here is an example: I’m at home, connected to the office network via VPN. I’d like to access the resource "munki.mydomain.com". Since the VPN is configured to use the DNS server on the office network, it would query this server and this server would resolve "munki.mydomain.com" into whatever IP I configured there. No way I get the public IP back, right? But this is exactly what I’d like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a record with a dot in it in the public DNS zone named "name.subdomain".

That way the public DNS server would only resolve this name to an address while you keep the whole subdomain in your internal DNS. You have to resolve the name in your internal domain too in order to be reachable by clients using the internal DNS.

**Edit:**
If you want that users of your internal DNS, who are coming via VPN, should use the external mirror, then you would have to resort to [split-horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS) and give out different addresses from your internal DNS server, depending on the address of the DNS client.

Comment: I didn’t try this yet but … Let’s stick to this example. I’m at home, connected to the office network via VPN. I’d like to access the resource "munki.mydomain.com". Since the VPN is configured to use the DNS server on the office network, it would query this server and this server would resolve "munki.mydomain.com" into whatever IP I configured there. No way I get the public IP back, right? But this is exactly what I’d like!

Comment: Would you please add this use case to your question, it was not clear for me and it may not clear for others reading your question.

Comment: Thank you, I think, this is, what I was looking for (without knowing it exists). Didn’t touch DNS much. I’m going to do some research.

Comment: Just one more thing. Initially I was thinking about adding "munki.mydomain.com" to the hosts file of the computers connecting via VPN, by adding the commands in `/etc/ppp/ip-up`. Would this be considered to be a dirty hack or would this be just fine?

Comment: One problem would be to *reliable remove* the entry when the VPN is not in use, for instance on a laptop that is taken to the office.